# Proteus always error at certain time (in this case 1.75 sec)

Tags: arduino-uno, freertos, rtos, proteus

I recently using FreeRTOS for college project, but somehow my proteus always had this fatal error (every time its difference error but always fatal error, sometime violation module DSIM.dll, sometime other .dll(s)). At first I thought it has something to do with my code, so I try to use another example code (simple template from the internet that does blinking LED, nothing complex) but its still error at the exact 1.75 sec even though at that guy's demo works splendidly. I think it has to do with xTaskDelay cause when I commented the delay line the tasks (its singular task I suppose cause the only running task is only the one with the higher priority) the program works. Thanks in advance

```
#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>
void setup()
//Initialize the Serial Monitor with 9600 baud rate
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println(F("In Setup function"));
//Set the digital pins 8 to 11 as digital output pins
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);

//Create three tasks with labels Task1, Task2 and Task3 and assign the priority as 1, 2 and 3 respectively. 
//We also create the fourth task labeled as IdelTask when there is no task in 
//operation and it has the highest priority.

 xTaskCreate(MyTask1, "Task1", 100, NULL, 1, NULL);
 xTaskCreate(MyTask2, "Task2", 100, NULL, 2, NULL);
 xTaskCreate(MyTask3, "Task3", 100, NULL, 3, NULL);
 xTaskCreate(MyIdleTask, "IdleTask", 100, NULL, 0, NULL);}

//We can change the priority of task according to our desire by changing the numeric’s //between NULL texts.

void loop()

{
//There is no instruction in the loop section of the code.
// Because each task executes on interrupt after specified time
}

//The following function is Task1. We display the task label on Serial monitor.

static void MyTask1(void* pvParameters)
{
 
  while(1)

  { 
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);

    digitalWrite(9,LOW); 

    digitalWrite(10,LOW);

    digitalWrite(11,LOW); 

    Serial.println(F("Task1"));

    vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}

//Similarly this is task 2

static void MyTask2(void* pvParameters)

{  
while(1)

  { digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);   
    Serial.println(F("Task2"));
    vTaskDelay(110/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}

//Similarly this is task 3

static void MyTask3(void* pvParameters)
{ 
while(1)
  { 
   digitalWrite(8,LOW);
   digitalWrite(9,LOW); 
   digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(11,LOW);
   Serial.println(F("Task3"));
   vTaskDelay(120/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}

//This is the idle task which has the lowest priority and calls when no task is running.

static void MyIdleTask(void* pvParameters)

{
  while(1)
   { 
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    digitalWrite(9,LOW); 
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
    Serial.println(F("Idle state"));
    delay(50);
  }  
}
```

[image: Error at 1.75]
[image: DSIM.dll]
[Source for the code](https://microcontrollerslab.com/use-freertos-arduino/)

Comment: I have not idea what a "proteus" is, but when I hover over the tag you have applied, it is clearly not that (though I don't know what a "JSON layout inflater" is either).

Comment: The code has no `xTaskDelay()`.  Did you mean `vTaskDelay`?

Comment: yes I mean vTaskDelay() lol, btw I already found the solution, it turns out the Proteus app is kinda corrupted so I went to google to download those .dll(s) files

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the Proteus app is kinda corrupted so I went to google to download those .dll(s) files